# How to extend AudioNode (native object without constructor)

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to put [this code](https://github.com/tambien/Piano/blob/master/src/Piano.js) to use (a tone.js piano, not written by me).

The piano class extends AudioNode like so:

```
class Piano extends AudioNode {

    constructor(){

        super()
        // piano specific stuff...
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate it, following the documentation, with

```
const piano = new Piano()
```

I get "TypeError: Illegal constructor".

What is then the correct way to extend a native object such as AudioNode that can't be instantiated with `new`? Did something change in the recent past so that the above code no longer works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AudioNode` in the example you are referring to is taken from the tone.js library. Take a look at the import statement:

```
import Tone, { Gain, Frequency, AudioNode, Buffer} from 'tone'
```

The error you get is a sign that you did not import the `AudioNode` from the library. That's why your code is using the native `AudioNode` type that cannot be extended.

Comment: why AudioNode cannot be extended?((